# search array in ruby and return results as collection of objects?

Tags: arrays, ruby, search

I am a noob in ruby, so take this with a grain of salt.

I have a `Person` which I've posted below. I am supposed to search the `people` array using last name, and return the results in an array so I can print it using a put statement such as `puts Person.search("Smith")`

here's the class that I am working on:

```
class Person

  attr_accessor :first_name,:last_name
  @@people = []

  def initialize(x,y)#should take 2 parameters for first_name and last_name
    @first_name = x
    @last_name = y  
    @@people << "#{@x} #{@y}"
  end
#my problem is that the function is returning nill. 
  def self.search(last_name)
  @results = []
  @@people.each do |variable|
      if variable.include? last_name 
              @results << variable
      end
    end
      @results
  end

  def to_s
    puts "#{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
    #return a formatted string as `first_name(space)last_name`
  end
end

p1 = Person.new("John", "Smith")
p2 = Person.new("John", "Doe")
p3 = Person.new("Jane", "Smith")
p4 = Person.new("Cool", "Dude")
```

I declared `results` as an empty array outside the block so I can alter its values and add items to it inside the block and maintain the changes outside the scope of the block. but for some reason the function doesn't seem to work. how can I debug the function so I can pinpoint the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your code.  You need to use

```
@@people << "#{x} #{y}"
```

`x` and `y` are local variables, and you should not prefix `@` to it as `@x` and `@y` will only work for instance variables

Comment: I have done so in the initialize function? I'm I missing something ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot use `@` to refer to local variables.

Comment: oh, i just noticed. thanks for pointing it out. problem solved ! thanks.